# Different standard deviation for same input from Wolfram and numpy

Tags: java, python, numpy, statistics

I am currently working on reimplementing some algorithm written in Java in Python. One step is to calculate the standard deviation of a list of values. The original implementation uses [`DescriptiveStatistics.getStandardDeviation`](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.1/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#getStandardDeviation%28%29) from the Apache Math 1.1 library for this. I use the standard deviation of numpy 1.5. The problem is, they give (very) different results for the same input. The sample I have is this:

```
[0.113967640255, 0.223095775796, 0.283134228235, 0.416793887842]
```

I get the following results:

```
numpy           : 0.10932134388775223
Apache Math 1.1 : 0.12620366805397404
Wolfram Alpha   : 0.12620366805397404
```

I checked with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) to get a third opinion. I do not think that such a difference can be explained by precision alone. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and what I could do about it?

**Edit**: Calculating it manually in Python gives the same result:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> v = [0.113967640255, 0.223095775796, 0.283134228235, 0.416793887842]
>>> mu = sum(v) / 4
>>> sqrt(sum([(x - mu)**2 for x in v]) / 4)
0.10932134388775223
```

Also, about not using it right:

```
>>> from numpy import std
>>> std([0.113967640255, 0.223095775796, 0.283134228235, 0.416793887842])
0.10932134388775223
```

Comment: Well, I can tell you that Apache and Wolfram are right?  And it is unlikely that Numpy is wrong.  So you are probably not using it right.  Post code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apache and Wolfram divide by N-1 rather than N.  This is a degrees of freedom adjustment, since you estimate μ. By dividing by N-1 you obtain an unbiased estimate of the population standard deviation.  You can change NumPy's behavior using the `ddof` option.

This is described in the NumPy documentation:

> The average squared deviation is
>   normally calculated as x.sum() / N,
>   where N = len(x). If, however, ddof is
>   specified, the divisor N - ddof is
>   used instead. In standard statistical
>   practice, ddof=1 provides an unbiased
>   estimator of the variance of the
>   infinite population. ddof=0 provides a
>   maximum likelihood estimate of the
>   variance for normally distributed
>   variables. The standard deviation
>   computed in this function is the
>   square root of the estimated variance,
>   so even with ddof=1, it will not be an
>   unbiased estimate of the standard
>   deviation per se.

Comment: You have no idea how happy your answer makes me. Thanks!

Comment: You can ask Wolfram|Alpha for the "population standard deviation" to get the same answer as NumPy did.